# React Native TabNavigator, Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I've just set up a React Navigation TabNavigator which works fine but I'm having issues with transitions between my views.

I get the following error message from trying to redirect the user to another page after a click on a button.

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

I'm super confused on how to make this work.

Here is the navigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ElemList from './src/components/ElemList';
import ElemShow from './src/components/ElemShow';

const RootTabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: ElemList,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
        <Ionicons
          name={focused ? 'ios-home' : 'ios-home-outline'}
          size={26}
          style={{ color: tintColor }}
        />
      ),
    },
    main: {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        show: { screen: ElemShow },
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my code:

```
onRowPress(data) {
this.props.navigation.navigate('ElemShow', {id: data})
};

render() {

const { key, elem } = this.props;

 return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.onRowPress(elem)}>
    <View style={styles.viewStyle} key={key}>
      <Text>Here is the info</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 )

}
```

Comment: Where do you define `elem` which you are passing to the function in the onPress?

Comment: @Max inside this.props, sorry forgot to mention that. But the error seems to come from the fact that navigate is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
this.props.navigation
```

Should be

```
this.props.navigator
```

Additionally I don't know that `navigate` is part of the screens API; typically you will use `push` or `resetTo`.

Comment: I still get undefined.

Comment: @Hugo are you calling `onRowPress` from within a component?

Comment: Yes I am. This component is a ListItem that I pass with a map function to my List.

Comment: Can you post the full component code, including the fix that you made per my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm going to close this issue I switch to React Native Router Flux, this React Navigation has too many bugs.

Comment: ok well if it's a child component you need to pass in {...this.props} to get the navigator